# Executar rotina agendada de tempo em tempo com android

Tags: android

Estou trabalhando em um aplicativo android que precisa verificar uma URL de X em X tempos.

A unica maneira que eu encontrei de agendar as tarefas seria com a classe `AlarmManager`, essa realmente seria a maneira mais correta? Alguém sugere uma classe diferente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `JobScheduler` te ajudará nisso.

[JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)

Comment: É possivel postar um exemplo da utilização para ajudar o AP a entender @AndréHenriques?